# How to get data referenced in another table in one MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would to select some data from mysql. However, some of the data stored in the table I am querying from are in codes and to get the text description I need to reference that data to another table.

```
TABLE: persons

SELECT id, first_name, last_name, address_code, customer_type_code
FROM persons
WHERE id = 1001    

TABLE: ref_address 

SELECT address_name FROM ref_address
WHERE address_code = 123


TABLE: ref_customer_type_code   

SELECT customer_type_name FROM ref_customer_type_code
WHERE customer_type_code = 456
```

How can I combine all three queries together to return id, first_name, last_name, address_name, customer_type_name in one query instead of querying them 3 times like this?

Comment: I suggest this as a great place for visualization of sql joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins and try join tutorials at sqlzoo.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please read the reference manual for `join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html).

In short, you need to define a relation between your tables (I use aliases just to make things a bit "cheaper" to write):

```sql
select p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.address_code, p.customer_type_code
     , ra.address_name
     , rctc.customer_type_name
from persons as p
     -- Join the persons table with the ref_address table, 
     -- using the address_code column of each table
     inner join ref_adress as ra 
                on p.address_code = ra.address_code
     -- Join the persons table with the ref_customer_type_code table
     -- using the customer_type_code column of each table
     inner join ref_customer_type_code as rctc 
                on p.customer_type_code = rctc.customer_type_code
where p.id = 1001
```

Notice that when you use multiple tables in a query it may be useful to define aliases to avoid having to write again and again the full name of the table. Also, it may be a good idea to *explicitly* specify each field's source table (by alias, if you are using it)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

In a `JOIN`, you specify two tables and how they are related to one another. In a single `SELECT` statement, you can have multiple `JOIN` clauses.

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.address_code, p.customer_type_code,
    a.address_name,
    t.customer_type_name

FROM
    persons p

    JOIN ref_address a
        ON p.address_code = a.address_code

    JOIN ref_customer_type_code t
        ON p.customer_type_code = t.customer_type_code

WHERE
    p.id = 1001
```

This query says that the table `persons` and `ref_address` should be linked, or "joined", by the related columns `address_code` which are available in each table. Same goes with the tables `persons` and `ref_customer_type_code` being linked by the columns `customer_type_code`.